# Grouping Logic with if conditions SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a data set structured like this:

```
CLIENT_ID    Segment      Yearmonth       
XXXX         A            201305         
XXXX         A            201306         
XXXX         B            201307         
XXXX         B            201308         
XXXX         C            201309         
XXXX         A            201310        
YYYY         D            201306
YYYY         D            201307
YYYY         C            201308
YYYY         D            201309
ZZZZ         E            201309
ZZZZ         E            201309
ZZZZ         E            201309
```

This is the output i am trying to get

```
CLIENT_ID    Segment       New_sequencing_Variable    
XXXX         A                       1
XXXX         B                       2
XXXX         C                       3
XXXX         A                       4
YYYY         D                       1
YYYY         C                       2
YYYY         D                       3
ZZZZ         E                       1
```

The code i have so far is:

```
HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS2 HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS3 ;
  set GENERAL.HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS ;
  by Client_ID ;
  if first.Client_ID then count = 0 ;
  count + 1 ;
  output HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS2 ; *output every record;
  if first.Client_ID then output HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS3 ;  *output first of each group;
run;
```

i need something like :

```
 if previous.segment <> current.segment then output HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS3
```

However, am able to get the first clientID, The segment and the sequencing variable but only the first client ID and the segment next to it in the output table HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS3 but only the first record.

How do i include the logic that output while grouping by client_id and yearmonth
 basically output a row row everytime a segment is different than the previous Yearmonths segment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically there already. Just add another count variable for the HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS3 dataset and a lag variable for the previous observations of segment.

```
data HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS2 HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS3;
    set HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS;
    by Client_ID;
    if first.Client_ID then do;
        count = 0;
        count2 = 0;
    end;
    count + 1;

    prev_segment = lag(segment);
    if prev_segment ne segment then do;
        count2 + 1;
        output HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS3;
    end;
    output HISTORICAL_SEGMENTS2;
    drop prev_segment;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for that!! this is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 2):

This can be simply achieved by the command "notsorted"

```
data abc;
input client_id $5. segment $2. yearmonth  ;
cards; 
xxxx a 201305
xxxx a 201306
xxxx b 201307
xxxx b 201308
xxxx c 201309
xxxx a 201310
yyyy d 201306
yyyy d 201307
yyyy c 201308
yyyy d 201309
zzzz e 201309
zzzz e 201309
zzzz e 201309
;
run;


data abc1;
set abc;
by client_id segment notsorted;
if first.segment;
if first.client_id then new_sequencing_variable = 0;
new_sequencing_variable + 1;
run;
```

**My Output:**

```
client_id   segment       new_sequencing_variable    
XXXX         A                       1
XXXX         B                       2
XXXX         C                       3
XXXX         A                       4
YYYY         D                       1
YYYY         C                       2
YYYY         D                       3
ZZZZ         E                       1
```

Let me know in case of any clarifications.